# "createjs" not being found. even thgough "createjs" library is being referenced

Tags: javascript

When I atttempted to use the key word "createjs" it is not being found, even though the "createjs" library has been referenced in my code.

Comment: Do you get a warning on the console that `create.js` failed to load. If no warming, check the network tab ( in developers tools) and down load the page again to see if the script is being retrieved by the browser. Please edit the question with the results you obtain. ( FYI  because comments are not intended for chat)

Comment: Is there any code you can share such that others can reproduce your problem?